# Is it necessary to build my own angular 2 development environment?

Tags: angular

On the angular 2 website,there is a quick start seed:[QuickStarter seed](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and there is also an [angular CLI tool](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for quickly build an angular project.So, does it necessary to build my own development environment by myself step by step?

Comment: Also there are few examples in our documentation site: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2#t=201612290610551316293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use Angular Cli it's as easy as typing

```
 ng new 'projectname'
```

and you have a complete project, top begin development on, or was that not what you meant?

Comment: This tool is great and it setup the development environment automatic.But I want to know why it works.So I want to know may I setup an angular 2 project manually.

Comment: In taht caase you could follow the guide here https://coursetro.com/posts/code/14/How-to-Install-Angular-2---The-Manual-Quickstart-Method but you'd be spending a lot of time setting stuff up, that's given to you for free by the angular team. You could just create the project with the cli tool, and then remove the packages from package.json that you do not need.

Answer (score 1):

**NO** ,
If you are using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) its not necessary to build your own development environment, but you must have [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed on your machine, and that is the only setup you need to do.

After that just  follow the steps [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) in order to create Angular2 project with peace.

But if you want to learn how where you need to put the compiled files and all other details I would suggest to go through the code and structure generated by Angular CLI